# Reformat XML in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

Is there an easy way to reformat an XML file while viewing it Visual Studio 2010. For example, if you open a generated app.config file, it might look like:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
<startup><supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.0"/></startup></configuration>
```

This is difficult to read, is there a way to instruct Visual Studio 2010 to format this, so that it looks more like:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.0"/>
  </startup>
</configuration>
```

Thanks for any help.

**Update:** With credit to Julien Hoarau for one of the answers. The answers are:

```
Edit -> Advanced -> Format Document (Ctrl+K, Ctrl+D)
Edit -> Advanced -> Format Selection (Ctrl+K, Ctrl+F)
```

Comment: Just want to mention a handy option: if you want to enable/disable auto-formatting on paste from clipboard
`Tools → Options → Text Editor → XML → Formatting → "On paste from clipboard" `

Answer (score 184, accepted):

Yes you can :

```
Edit > Advanced > Format document (Ctrl+K Ctrl+D)
```

Comment: ... and if it's from a file, the file extension should be relevant to the format... like .xml or .html

Comment: In VS2022, I could seem the shortcut had been changed to Ctrl+E, Ctrl+D. But anyways thanks for the insight, quite useful!

Comment: This does not fix whitespace issues

Answer (score 6):

If you want to leave your right hand free to do something else, you can use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>.

Not sure how this is different from <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>.

Answer (score 2):

Not 100% sure about VS2010, but in VS2015 if you copy and paste a long string of XML into an .XML document, it will automatically reformat it.

("Format Document" is usually the way to go, just mentioning another option.)